# Linq2Dynamodb run expression string on Table

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, amazon-dynamodb

I have an ASP.NET Web API site which records all objects in AWS DynamoDb. I took a quick look at linq2Dynamodb. It seems that the common way to use it is like:

```
var moviesTable = ctx.GetTable<Movie>();
var inceptionMovie = moviesTable
    .Where(m => m.Genre == "Thriller" && m.Title == "Inception")
    .Single();
```

But I want some API like:

```
moviesTable.Execute(string querystring);
```

The reason is that from the Web API, I usually get some query like:

```
http://host/service.svc/Orders?$filter=ShipCountry eq 'France'
```

I'd like to pass the filter string "ShipCountry eq 'France'" here. Do anyone know if there is a way for me to do this? Thanks.

Comment: try dynamic linq:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your reply. I took a look at dynamic linq. It takes string. But what I want here is to have linq2Dynamodb library take a string. Basically, I want the string to be converted to AWS DynamoDb's QueryFilter.

Answer (score 0):

With Linq2DynamoDb you can expose your DynamoDb tables as OData resources. Please, see the [doc here](https://linq2dynamodb.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exposing%20LINQ2DynamoDB.DataContext%20as%20an%20OData-endpoint).

As soon as you have an OData resource, you can query it with OData queries of any valid kind. 
And you can use any OData client library for that. E.g. with [System.Data.Services.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext(v=vs.113).aspx) you would say something like:

```
var entities = myContext.Execute<MyEntityType>(new Uri("<here goes URI with valid OData query string>"), "GET", true);
```

or just construct a LINQ query on the client side.

The drawback is that you will need to host your OData service somewhere (DynamoDb itself doesn't support OData, so that's the reason).

The advantages are:

- you will be able to cache your data in ElastiCache.
- you will be able to implement custom authentication inside your service.

Sorry for a bit late answer.